# Artin exercise 1.3.4.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

I am trying to solve:

> How much can a matrix be simplified if both row and column operations are allowed?

I can't figure out what the problem is getting at or what Artin means by "allowed." It's my understanding that both row and column operations *are* allowed, and both or either can reduce a matrix to reduced-row echelon form. The "most" it can be simplified is in fact its reduced-row echelon form, but I don't need both row and column operations in order to get there.

Am I missing the point? There must be more to this problem.

Comment: We can obtain more than the RREF by the elimination of elements out of the diagonal.

Comment: See for example [this](https://tartarus.org/gareth/maths/Linear_Algebra/row_operations.pdf).

Comment: If the phrase "row and column operations" refers to "*elementary* row and column operations", then every matrix $A$ can be simplified to a diagonal matrix in the form of $\operatorname{diag}(a,1,\ldots,1)$ when $A$ is invertible or $\operatorname{diag}(1,\ldots,1,0,\ldots,0)$ when $A$ is singular.

Comment: @user1551 It makes sense to me in general that I can use row operations to produce the RREF and then column operations to eliminate all remaining non-zero entries corresponding to free variables. But what if the column is entirely 0's and this isn't possible? I'm trying to craft a counterexample where there are some entries for which this isn't possible. I think what you're implying is it's possible to interchange columns and put those columns on the left.